# Remap indices from list of tuples to values in a dataframe and create a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples. Something like this.
results = [(24578, 23611, 0.875), (27543, 23611, 0.875), (27524, 27458, 1.0).......]

Each tuple in the list is (index of the first item, index of the second item, score).

How can I parse this so the instead of indices of items, I get the actual item itself.

I understand doing this --> pd.DataFrame(results, columns =['First Item', 'Second Item', 'Score'])
gives you a table of indices and score.

| First Item | Second Item | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 24578 | 23611 | 0.875 |
| 27543 | 23611 | 0.42 |

However, eventually, I would want a dataframe with the two items side by side and their score on the third column.

Something like this:

| First Item | Second Item | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Ape | 0.875 |
| Airplane | Ape | 0.42 |

Update:
What I have tried so far is:

1. Unpack the results list of tuples

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you can achieve what you need by `pandas.DataFrame.from_records()`, for example:

```py
import pandas as pd

lst = [(24578, 23611, 0.875), (27543, 23611, 0.875), (27524, 27458, 1.0)]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(lst, columns=['First Item', 'Second Item', 'Score'])
```

Returns:

```
First Item  Second Item  Score
0       24578        23611  0.875
1       27543        23611  0.875
2       27524        27458  1.000
```

If you also have a list of your items, just loop through it:

```py
items = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Pear']

items_score_dict = {'First Item':[], 'Second Item':[], 'Score':[]}
for x in lst:
#     print((x[0], x[1], x[2]))
    items_score_dict['First Item'].append(items[x[0]])
    items_score_dict['Second Item'].append(items[x[1]])
    items_score_dict['Score'].append(x[1])
print(pd.DataFrame(items_score_dict))
```

Produces:

```
  First Item Second Item  Score
0     Banana        Pear      2
1       Pear      Banana      1
2      Apple      Banana      1
```

Comment: I can already achieve this. I want to retrieve the item in the dataframe that is referred by the index. In the above example 24578 is an index for first item in a dataframe. Sorry if the way I worded it was confusing.